# Error calling on macro from a different file

Tags: excel, vba, macros

> "Object doesn't support this property or method"

is the error I am getting trying to call on another macro from my current file.  I am looping through several excel workbooks and need to run a macro within the files I am looping through.

```
Sub SaveBacktestingFiles()
    Dim wBCalc As Workbook
    Dim wBRaw As Workbook
    Dim wBRun As Workbook

    For Each c In Worksheets("Static").Range("FILE_RANGE").Cells
        Range("Date_Range").Value = c
        Calculate
        FS_Name = Range("FS_Name_Range").Value
        FO_RawName = Range("FO_RawName_Range").Value
        Set wBRun = ActiveWorkbook
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Range("FO_CalcName_Range").Value, ReadOnly:=True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FS_Name
        Set wBCalc = ActiveWorkbook
        Application.Run (wBCalc & "!FilterLoop")
        ActiveWorkbook.Close True
    Next
End Sub
```

Instead of: `Application.Run (wBCalc & "!FilterLoop")` I tried 
`Application.Run ("'" & FO_CalcName_Range & "'!ReApplyDump")` which contains the full path.
I also tried with no luck: `Application.Run ("'" & wBCalc & "'!ReApplyDump")`  I had this work before but cant get it to work for the life of me.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the edit tarzanbappa.  I tried to get the post as readable as possible but it looks cleaner with your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `wbCalc` is a workbook and not a string. Hence, the concatenation that you are attempting doesn't make sense.

Replace

```
Application.Run (wBCalc & "!FilterLoop")
```

By

```
Application.Run (wBCalc.Name & "!FilterLoop")
```

Without access to your code for `FilterLoop`, I can't test this, though it should get you closer to your goal.