# Why isn't this a type mismatch?

Tags: vba, excel

I answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37934485/4996248) question, apparently to OP's satisfaction, but still find their question puzzling. Their question involved an expression in which a workbook object was being concatenated with a string, triggering `Run-time Error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method`. You can reproduce this sort of error by simply typing

```
?"Hello, " & ThisWorkbook
```

In the Immediate Window.

My question is -- why does this raise *that* error, instead of a error 13 -- type mismatch? A reasonable guess is that VBA tries to find a default property for a workbook object and that a default property doesn't exist. But, if so, I would expect it to be the following error from Microsoft's list of Visual Basic 6.0 error codes: `Automation object doesn't have a default value (Error 443)`.

It is mostly of academic interest, but if the result of concatenating an object without a default property with a string is always Error 438, and that is the only way of triggering Error 438 rather than possibly another error when concatenating a string with an object, then the following code might be of use:

```
Function HasDefault(O As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    If Not IsObject(O) Then Exit Function
    On Error Resume Next
    i = Len("Hello, " & O)
    If Err.Number = 438 Then
        HasDefault = False
    Else
        HasDefault = True
    End If
End Function
```

I've tested this on a variety of objects, and for those I've tested it on it has returned False exactly when `_Default` doesn't show up as a (hidden) member of the object when viewed in the Object Browser. Nevertheless, I don't quite trust this function and am still puzzled by what is going on here.

Comment: The answer you have given yourself seems perfectly fine to me. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VBA will try and convert the expressions on each side of the `&` operator to a data value. The language spec states that:

- If the value type of the expression’s target variable is a class:
- If the declared type of the target is Variant, runtime error 9
  (Subscript out of range) is raised.
- If the declared type of the target is not Variant, and the target has
  a public default Property Get or function, the data value’s value is
  the result of invoking this default member for that target with this
  argument list. This consumes the argument list.
- Otherwise, runtime error 438 (Object doesn’t support this property or
  method) is raised.

As regards your function, I'd just use:

```
callbyname(O, "_Default", VbGet)
```

which will raise a 438 error as appropriate.

Comment: Good answer, I searched the documentation a bit (which is how I found that obscure error 443), but apparently not with the right keywords.